# Where is the WebIDL definition for window.JSON?

Tags: javascript, ecma, webidl

I'm looking for the WebIDL definition for JSON.parse method. I looked into the [Mozila's WebIDL definitions](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/tree/master/dom/webidl) at GitHub but I couldn't find. Where is that?

Comment: JSON object is a part of JavaScript, it's not a DOM object.

Comment: @Teemu The [Mozila's WebIDL documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/WebIDL_bindings) says "All WebIDL files should be placed in dom/webidl" so I have guessed JavaScript IDLs are in that directory.